# Unable to get login in if else loop

Tags: java, loops

I have four inputs like (`int age1, int age2, int age3, int age4`). I need to print how many of those numbers are greater than 60. For Example: if the values given are 20, 40, 65 and 80, the program should print 2. Regards !

Comment: There is no such thing as an `if-else-loop`.

Comment: Please share any code you've written that attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include the code you've tried so far. I suggest reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int[] ages = {sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt()};
   int num = getGreaterNum(ages, 60);
   System.out.println(num);
}

public static int getGreaterNum(int[] nums, int condition) {
   int greater= 0;
   for(int num : nums) {
       if(num > condition) {greater++;}
   }
   return greater;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response but in my case the numbers I am taking are from user. I am using Scanner to take the inputs. so I need to skip the array part.

Comment: This was a perfect one! Thanks for this. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes new coders (and some self-taught professors) think it would be a good idea to dynamically create or access variable names, the variables are often named something like these:

```
matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, matrix4, etc.
```

But it's not good with variables. Try :

```
int greater = 0;
int[] myNum = {20, 40, 65, 80};
for(int i :myNum){
   if(i > 60){
     grater += 1;
   }
}

System.out.println(greater);
```

Answer (score 0):

using variable arguments you don't need to specify how many arguments you need to pass into your method. using variable arguments feature in java you can try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = calculate(10, 77, 56, 90, 65);
    System.out.println("Result is : " + result);
}


private static int calculate(int... numbers) {
   int counter = 0;
   for (int num : numbers) {
       if (num > 60) {
          counter++;
       }
   }

   return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String args[])
{Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int count=0;
while(s.hasNext()){
int a=s.nextInt();
if(a>60)
count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
}
```

That's how you can do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Appreciate your response.